# Laravel: Missing argument

Tags: php, laravel

I am building this website and I want to pass url parameters

http://movies.com/people?genre=action

Should generate all the people listed with genre=action

This is my route

```
Route::resource(Str::slug(trans('main.people')), 'ActorController');
```

This is my ActorController

```
public function index($input)
{

if (isset($input['genre']) && $input['genre'] != 'all')
    {
        return $this->actor->where('genre', 'like', '$input');

        return View::make('Actor.All')->withActors($actors);
    }
    else
    {

         return View::make('Actor.All')->withActors($actors);
}
}
```

I keep receiving this error
 ErrorException
Missing argument 1 for ActorController::index()

Comment: try using laravel's input class :
`http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input`

Comment: Hi the Input class here only grabs GET/POST data.  How do I send input from the URL?

Comment: input from the URL is `GET` data

Comment: @Stephenmelb the input class will fetch query strings fine, but you'll need to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

Query strings aren't passed down automatically to controller's method, you need to fetch them manually:

```
public function index()
{
  if(Input::has('genre') && Input::get('genre') != 'all') {
     $this->actor->where('genre', 'like', Input::get('genre'));

  }
  return View::make('Actor.all')->withActors($this->actor);
}
```

Comment: Hi I think its passing the variable but now I am getting Call to undefined method Lib\Repository\Actor\DbActor::where()

Comment: Because I'm only guessing where you're taking that $actor variable from, I suppose you inizialize it in the constructor? Is it an DB class, right?

Comment: public function __construct(DbActor $actor, ActorValidator $validator, Options $options)
 {
  $this->actor = $actor;
  $this->options = $options;
  $this->validator = $validator;
 }

Comment: Does your class has a where method? It doesn't look like an Eloquent model, what is it?

Comment: Its eloquent but my actor class doesnt have a where method

Comment: Hi Damien  I've changed a few things with the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622738/input-returns-empty-query-in-error  I'm getting a different error now.  Can you help please?

Comment: Your new code is very different, so my answer has nothing to do with it. Please read the Laravel manual to understan how thing works