# Input returns empty query in error

Tags: php, laravel

I have a movies website that I want to allow people to search by genre

movies.com/people/action/genre

The Route

```
Route::get('people/{genre}/genre', array('uses' => 'ActorController@genre', 'as' => 'people.genre'));
```

The ActorController@genre

```
public function genre()
{

    $genre=Input::get('genre');
        $actors = $this->actor->allgenre($genre);
            return View::make('Actor.All')->withActors($actors);

}
```

This grabs all the actors from the db

```
function allGenre($genre)
{

        return $this->actor->where('genre', 'like', '$genre')->orderBy('views', 'desc')->paginate(24);

}
```

This is returning no results, when it should be returning results because if I go

```
function allGenre($genre)
{

        return $this->actor->where('genre', 'like', 'action')->orderBy('views', 'desc')->paginate(24);

}
```

Results show up

Comment: Why you tag it as symfony2  ?

Comment: Sorry cause im using the symfony2 package.

Answer (score 1):

When you use that routing, the $genre variable would be bound the the controller:

```
public function genre($genre)
{
  $actors = $this->actor->allgenre($genre);
  return View::make('Actor.All')->withActors($actors);
}
```

While in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21621211/laravel-missing-argument/21621596) you used query strings, so you needed Input::get('key'), now you changed the url, and you don't use resource controllers anymore, so you must go back to the "usual" way

Comment: Hi Damien Thanks for sharing , but it is still not returning results when I go movies.com/people/action/genre.  How do I check if the $genre variable is getting passed to the allgenre function?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work

```
function allGenre($genre)
{

    return $this->actor->where('genre', 'like', $genre)->orderBy('views', 'desc')->paginate(24);

}
```

Apparently Laravel doesn't accept '$genre' with the ' around the variable